# How to configure and enable a JMS Listener to consume messages based on some condition?

Tags: java, spring-boot, message-queue, spring-jms

I have two listeners(`fooMessages` and `barMessages`) in my application, and both of them are connected to same queue. At one point of time only one listener will consume the message from the queue based on some condition. In `application.yml` file if `fooEnabled` is set to `true` then `fooMessages` listener should consume the messages and if `fooEnabled` is set to `false` then `barMessages` listener should consume the messages.

Listeners:

```java
@JMSListener(destination="${queueName}", selector = "${selectorName}")
public void fooMessages(Message message) {
   // foo logic
}
    
@JMSListener(destination="${queueName}", selector = "${selectorName}")
public void barMessages(Message message) {
   // bar logic
}
```

`application.yml` file:

```
queueName: myqueue
selectorName: "priority=medium"
fooEnable: true
```

How can I configure the listener to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Give each listener an `id`
2. Configure the container factory to not automatically start the listeners https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.integration.spring.jms.listener.auto-startup
3. Start the container(s) manually using the `JmsListenerEndpointRegistry` bean - `registry.getListenerContainer("fooListener").start();`

```java
@Bean
ApplicationRunner runner(@Value("${fooEnabled}") boolean fooEnabled, 
        @Value("${barEnabled}") boolean barEnabled, JmsListenerEndpointRegistry registry) {
    return args -> {
        if (fooEnabled) ...
    }
}
```